# how to log all the sql queiers are run in server in asp?

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, logging

I have a classic asp code with access database, and i am new to it. I need to log all the sql queries happen in system since the system seems loosing data. can any one help with with this?

Thanks

Comment: that exists in MS-access ?????

Comment: @Rafael yes it is an microsoft access which i need to fix. and it is not my code

Comment: If you are using Access 2010, data macros may help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973807.aspx). They may be slow in a web app (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=591266)

Answer (score 0):

Ms-Access does not support transaction logging like the more advanced database servers, the only way to do this would be if you could control the environment whereby any SQL is run, in this case within the front-end application. You could then trigger a routine to save the executed string. However, if people have background access to the database and can run their own queries whenever they like then you have little chance of logging these.